# could not load module rsyslog lmnsd_gtls.so

Tags: drivers, apt, rsyslog

The rsyslog module is showing up in system log `/var/log/syslog` as message repeated.  rsyslog was also showing 99% cpu use in `top` at one point, possibly unrelated.

`tail /var/log/syslog`

```
Dec  1 22:18:16 here rsyslogd-2066: could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so', dlopen: /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]
Dec  1 22:18:56 here rsyslogd-2066: last message repeated 4 times
```

`lsb_release -a`

Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:        12.04

`sudo apt-cache showpkg rsyslog`

Package: rsyslog
Versions: 
5.8.6-1ubuntu8.5

Related Question : How do I find that `lmnsd_gtls.so` is related to `rsyslog-gnutls` ?

Answer (score 16):

Get the missing module by installing the `rsyslog-gnutls` package.

`sudo apt-get install rsyslog-gnutls`

see also http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/06/install-splunk-and-send-logs-to-splunk-with-rsyslog-over-tcp-with-ssl/

see also http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/encrypting-remote-syslog-with-tls-ssl

Check to see if the module file exists :

`ls -la /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so`

Comment: It was /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me when I was trying to set up syslog with tls certificate similar to [this](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/encrypting-remote-syslog-with-tls-ssl). Rsyslog in few of the systems start as `root` and then fall to user `syslog`. There is a possibility that the certificate is not readable by the syslog user.

Check it using:

```
sudo -H -u syslog bash -l -c 'less <path to the certificate>'
```

if you get `Permission Denied`, add `read` permissions for your `syslog` user, and restart rsyslog.

Answer (score -1):

Dec  1 22:18:16 here rsyslogd-2066: could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so', dlopen: /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]

I have encountered recently above error, and the solution was to place  certificates under /etc/rsyslog.d.

Reference: https://www.loggly.com/docs/rsyslog-tls-configuration/