# How do I find a package that contains a given module?

Tags: apt, syslog, rsyslog

How do I find which package contains a given module ?  I had a missing module in `/usr/lib/` , and was trying to figure out which package would fix the problem using `apt-get`

The error was in `/var/log/syslog` involving `lmnsd_gtls.so` and the solution was to install the package `rsyslog-gnutls` .

See also [could not load module rsyslog lmnsd_gtls.so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384858/could-not-load-module-rsyslog-lmnsd-gtls-so/)

Answer (score 2):

There's (at least) two options.

### Package content search

You can use the package contents search on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), e.g. to search for [all packages that contain a file named 'lmnsd_gtls.so'](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=lmnsd_gtls.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any). This is usually is the fastest way, but only works for the official Ubuntu repositories.

---

### apt-file

You can also use `apt-file`, which allows for the searching of repository file lists.

1. Install it

   `sudo apt-get install apt-file`
2. Update the file cache by downloading the repository indexes of all configured repositories.

   `sudo apt-file update`
3. Search for files, e.g. `lmnsd_gtls.so`. Note: You can also use full or partial paths in the file name.

   `apt-file search lmnsd_gtls.so`

The last command lists all packages containing `lmnds_gtls.so`.

```
rsyslog-gnutls: /usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so
```